# Merge files in the directory with specific names Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i am trying to merge those file names specified in the array into single.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ReportNames=A B C D"
for %%a in (%ReportNames%) do (
   echo %%a
   echo/
   type %%a_* > %%a
)
```

**input:** the file in the folder would be A_1123 , A_110 , A_1140 etc

**output:** should be single file A

but the above code gives file path not specified error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are no any question in your text. What is your question?

Comment: its not working as expected

Comment: Fix path not specified: `echo %%a_* > %%a`

Comment: ya but when i do type %%a_* > %%a its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is sounds like you need to concatenate content of that files, so try something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ReportNames=A B C D"
for %%a in (%ReportNames%) do (
  echo %%a
  echo/
  for /r %%b in (%%a_*) do (
    echo %%b
    echo/
    type %%b >> %%a
  )
)
```

(here I've replaced `type %%a_* > %%a` by processing of all files with that mask `%%a_*`)

Comment: What is 'merging'? My code concatenates content of all files with mask 'A_*' into one single file 'A'. And what do you expect? Add more information in the question about desired result.